# Issues running script to compare data between tables on different servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a simple script that checks to see if there is data in one column in a DB on one server that does not exist in a differently names column on a second server. I am new to scripts in SQL and I am not sure what my issue is. I am seeing two errors, one "Must declare the table variable "@CaseNum"." and the other is "The multi-part identifier "SQLTEST10\SQLTEST10.RISK_TEST.dbo.Incident" could not be bound."

What am I missing?

```
Declare @CurrentYear DateTime = YEAR(getdate());
Declare @EventNumber nvarchar(30) = dbo.Details;
Declare @RCaseNum nvarchar(30) = @CurrentYear + @EventNumber;
Declare @CaseNum nvarchar(30) = [SQLTEST10\SQLTEST10].[RISK_TEST].[dbo].[Incident];

Select @EventNumber
From dbo.Details
Where @EventNumber NOT IN
    (Select @RCaseNum
     From @CaseNum)
```

Comment: 1st what you want to store in "@CaseNum", if data from Incident table then, you need to define as table with appropriate schema. Refer this https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/ for "@table"

Comment: You can't use variables in the place of tables or columns. To create something like this you'll have to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot assign a table to a variable. And since you want to evaluate the EventNumber you have to use a cursor because a variable can hold only one value at a time. This may not be a real time solution because i don't know how your data looks like but definitely keep you moving ahead.

Declare @EventNumber nvarchar(30) = 2

Declare @CurrentYear DateTime = YEAR(getdate())

select convert(int,@EventNumber) + convert(int,@CurrentYear)

Declare @sql nvarchar(2000)

Declare @CaseNum nvarchar(30)

declare cur cursor for select EventNumber from dbo.Details

open cur

fetch next from cur into @EventNumber

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

begin

set @sql = N'select @CaseNum = CaseNumber from [RISK_TEST].[dbo].[Incident]

where CaseNumber != ' + @EventNumber + ''

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@casenum int out', @casenum out

fetch next from cur into @EventNumber

end

close cur

deallocate cur

This should work.

Comment: That looks great. I however get the error, Must declare the scalar variable "@CaseNum".

Comment: I have replaced exec(@sql) with sp_executesql to return the @casenum value